# Get empty hash value from url with Javascript

Tags: javascript, url

Using `window.location.hash` I get this:

```
http://example.com         --> ''
http://example.com#        --> ''
http://example.com#ahihah  --> '#ahihah'
```

However, I need to distinguish between these two cases:

```
http://example.com         --> ''
http://example.com#        --> '#'
http://example.com#ahihah  --> '#ahihah'
```

So when there is no hash in the url (first case) it's ok to have an empty string but I want to have the value `'#'` if there is the hash sign. Is this possible in JavaScript?

---

I already tried with this.

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
var href = window.location.href;
if (hash !== '') {
  return link.hash;
}
if (href.slice(-1) === '#') {
  return '#';
}
return '';
```

But looks like an error-prone method. Could be that a query string in the url ends with `#` and the function will fall into the second `if` returning `'#'` instead of `''`?

Comment: A querystring can't end with `#`, that would mean there's a location hash after the querystring ?

Comment: Why do you need to know this anyway, it seems like an X/Y problem ?

Comment: @adeneo I just added what I tried. I could remove it and ask directly for the problem. I'm looking for a good and robust solution and I'm not sure about mine.

Comment: And again, what's the use case? Generally it shouldn't matter if the URL ends with an empty hash or doesn't have a hash at all, it's the same thing?

Comment: @adeneo I get an url and I need to do something different if there is an empty hash or if there isn't any hash. Also browsers behave different in two cases: if I'm to `http://example.com` and I go to `http://example.com` (e.g. clicking a link) the page will be reloaded while if I go to `http://example.com#` the page will scroll on top. I don't know if I answered your question? I just need to do two different things in the first and the second case.

Comment: @adeneo Also I need to be generic and working with any url. So, I was not sure my solution works on any possible url. The query string ending with `#` is just an example of an url that could be wrong for my function. For what I knew, there could be some cases on which my function fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method works fine.

A query string cannot have a `#` in it (it would need to be encoded as `%23`, and then `href.slice(-1) === 3`), since that would be interpreted as the start of a hash, not part of the query string.